# Command to find the sudo su jenkins occurences in a RHEL Linux box

Tags: linux, jenkins, sudo, permission-denied, rhel7

My requirement is to review the occurrences of `sudo su jenkins` command usage in a RHEL VM. I tried the below command and got permission denied error. Is there any other specific command which gives me the output of occurrences of the `sudo su jenkins` usage. I need to remove the `sudo su` and see the impact

**command:**

```
tail var/log/secure | grep jenkins
```

**Error:**

```
Permission denied
```

I tried this command inside Jenkins user only

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Permission for /var/log/secure file is: -rw-------. So jenkins user can't access this file.
Use  `sudo cat /var/log/secure | grep jenkins`